# Python3 - How do you run threads in a While True: loop, and only restart threads that have finished?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, for-loop, while-loop

Here's my current code. It runs the function 'test1' on three different threads.

Each thread takes a different amount of time to complete.

Each thread gets locked, and only unlocked when the function completes.

Each thread's start also creates a reset lock that will only unlock when the thread is reset.

I would like each thread to start, loop through the code as quick as possible, restarting threads that have finished, and not restarting threads that haven't finished, until they do!

You'll need to change the lock paths to suit your OS/User.

I have tried making new dictionaries, tried updating the current dictionary, etc, nothing has worked so far.

```
    import threading
import time
from quicklock3 import singleton
import os

def test1(duration, message, name):
    time.sleep(duration)
    os.remove('/Users/engineering/.lock/%s.lock' % name)#Unlock Thread
    print(message+'----------------------------------------------------------------FINISHED')

ServiceDict = {
    'T1':threading.Thread(daemon=True, target=test1, args=(20,"T1 FINISHED", "T1")),
    'T2':threading.Thread(daemon=True, target=test1, args=(5,"T2 FINISHED", "T2")),
    'T3':threading.Thread(daemon=True, target=test1, args=(1,"T3 FINISHED", "T3"))
}

for Service in ServiceDict:
    try:
        os.remove('/Users/engineering/.lock/%s.lock' % Service)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    try:
        os.remove('/Users/engineering/.lock/%s_reset.lock' % Service)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        
time.sleep(5)
        
while True:
    
    for Service in ServiceDict:
        print(Service)
        time.sleep(2)
        if os.path.exists('/Users/engineering/.lock/%s_reset.lock' % Service):
            print("NO THREAD UPDATE FOR "+Service)
        else:
            print("UPDATING DICTIONARY FOR "+Service)
            ServiceDict[Service] = ServiceDict.pop(Service)
            print(ServiceDict)
            time.sleep(2)
            
    for Service in ServiceDict:
        if os.path.exists('/Users/engineering/.lock/%s_reset.lock' % Service):
            print('RESET ALREADY LOCKED...'+Service)
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        else:
            singleton(Service) #Lock Thread
            print('LOCKING THREAD... '+Service)
            singleton(Service+'_reset') #Lock Reset
            print("STARTING THREAD... "+Service)
            ServiceDict[Service].start()
            time.sleep(1)
        
    for Service in ServiceDict:
        if os.path.exists('/Users/engineering/.lock/%s.lock' % Service):
            print("SCRIPT STILL RUNNNING... "+Service)
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        else:
            print("RESETTING THREAD... "+Service+' ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++RESETTING')
            ServiceDict[Service].join()
            os.remove('/Users/engineering/.lock/%s_reset.lock' % Service)#Unlock Reset
            time.sleep(1)
            
    print("LOOP FINISHED") 
    time.sleep(1)
```

Currently receiving a RuntimeError: dictionary keys changed during iteration

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-449e94d77d30> in <module>
     31     time.sleep(5)
     32 
---> 33     for Service in ServiceDict:
     34         print(Service)
     35         time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: what are you expecting the line `ServiceDict[Service] = ServiceDict.pop(Service)` to do?

Comment: Re, "dictionary keys changed during iteration." That's got nothing to do with multithreading. That's entirely because of what your main thread does. You are not allowed to modify a dictionary while you are iterating over it.

Comment: P.S., It's usually better to have long-lived threads that loop instead of having a loop that contually creates new short-lived threads. Consider using a [_thread pool_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) instead of explicitly creating threads. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I'm thinking that a thread pool might be a good fit.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen That line was to update a thread within the dictionary. So if the tread had finished, then that thread entry in the dictionary would be updated. Each thread needs to be redefined before the thread can start again so something like that is needed for it to work.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yes I understand that error is due to the dictionary changing while it's being iterated over. Do you know of how I would be able to iterate over this dictionary and perhaps write the updates to a new dictionary, that would then be used for the rest of the script?

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thanks for the tip I will look into thread pool. Essentially what I'm trying to achieve is a script that will loop indefinitely, starting threads, and restarting threads when they are finished. Of course the threads take differing amounts of time to complete, so lock files are used to see if a thread has finished or not. If it's finished then restart the thread, if it hasn't finished, don't restart it. Fairly simple idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you know of how I would be able to iterate over this dictionary...?

I would break the data structure into two parts; An immutable set of "thread slots" (i.e., dictionary keys) over which you can iterate, and a second part, a dictionary that maps slot->thread or slot->whatever, that you can mutate during the iteration.

The keys can just be integers, so...

```py
for slot in range(NUM_THREADS):
   ...access and mutate ServiceDict[slot] here...
```

---

> what I'm trying to achieve is a script that will loop indefinitely, starting threads, and restarting threads when they are finished.

I'm saying, change your architecture. Don't continually re-start threads. Don't let the threads die.

In your mind, you need to divorce the idea of threads from the idea of work that threads perform. A thread is a thing that executes your code. I like to use the word "task" to describe the things that you want your threaded code to do.

In your present architecture, you create one thread for each task, and then you let the thread die when the task is completed. I'm saying, keep the threads alive, and let each thread wait for a next task instead of dying when it finishes its current task. Depending on the size of the tasks, this can be *much* more efficient than creating and destroying a thread for each task. Creating and destroying threads is expensive.

That's where a [*thread pool*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) comes in. It's exactly the purpose for which thread pools were invented. A thread pool keeps a stable of "worker threads" that sit around waiting for tasks. When your main thread (or *any* thread) calls `thread_pool.submit(new_task, ...task args...)`, one of the workers will pick that `new_task` from the pool's task queue, perform the task, and then go back to waiting for the next task.

Each call to `thread_pool.submit(...)` returns a [*Future*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) object. Your main thread (or whatever thread) can use the `Future` to wait for the task to be finished and optionally, to get a result from the finished task. Or, you can just throw the `Future` away if you don't want to wait.

---

> lock files are used to see if a thread has finished or not.

Sometimes, it can be reasonable to use the file system as a means for communication between *processes,* but there are *much* more efficient ways to communicate between threads within a single process.

Here's a few examples, arranged in increasing order of power.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html?highlight=event#threading.Event

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html?highlight=semaphore#threading.Semaphore

https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html?highlight=queue#queue.Queue

Describing all of the ways in which you could use those things is a book level topic. In fact, here's a link to a free book that just talks about things you can do with Semaphores. It's an *old* book, and there may be newer better ways to do some of the things it shows you, but my point is for you to see just how powerful even a simple thing like a Semaphore can be.

https://greenteapress.com/wp/semaphores/

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed and concise answer, much appreciated. Every time I  feel close to getting my code up and running, I find out about a better method/architecture and end up having to re-write the whole thing! Hopefully this is the last time! Thanks again.